# Online waiting: django submit form and display result in same page

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax, forms

I have an emergent task to make a web page which allow user to input some data and the backend do some calculation and the result needs to be displayed in the same page just below the input field (like air ticket online price check).

I am new to django and html. below is my first test web page of a simple online calculator to try to figure out how to make such web service.

I found a problem that when clicking the "submit" button, it tends to jump to a new web page or a new web tab. this is not what I want. Once the user input the data and click "submit" button, I want the "result" field on the page directly show the result (i.e. partially update only this field) without refresh/jump to the new page. Also I want the user input data kept in the same page after clicking "submit".

I saw there might be several different ways to do this work, iframe/AJAX. However, I have been searching/trying for answers and solutions for several days and none of the answers really work for this very basic simple question!!

html:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
      <label>num_1:</label>
      <input type="text" name="num_1" value="1" placeholder="Enter value" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>num_2:</label>
      <input type="text" name="num_2" value="2" placeholder="Enter value" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>{{ result }}</div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

view.py

```
def post_list(request):
    result = 0
    if request.method == "POST":
        num1 = request.POST.get('num_1')
        num2 = request.POST.get('num_2')
        result = int(num1) + int(num2)
        print(request.POST)
        print(result)

    context = {
        'result': result
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [htmx.org](https://htmx.org/docs/) which makes this really simple without having to write any actual JS.

For your example:

**(1)** You add the htmx JS (which is only about 10k) to your HTML, and use `hx-post` and `hx-target` to trigger the ajax calls on your form. With these the form will fire an AJAX request, and the `hx-target` tells htmx to take the response (which you want to be only the result of your calculation) and put it in the div without refreshing the whole page.
See [docs](https://htmx.org/docs/) for more details on this.
Note also I gave an `id` to the div containing the result.
You will need to replace `hx-post="{% url 'blog:post_list' %}"` with the correct name to your view (which we don't know as you didn't post your `urls.py`).

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" hx-post="{% url 'blog:post_list' %}" hx-target="#result">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div>
            <label>num_1:</label>
            <input type="text" name="num_1" value="1" placeholder="Enter value" />
            </div>
            <div>
            <label>num_2:</label>
            <input type="text" name="num_2" value="2" placeholder="Enter value" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div id="result">{{ result }}</div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.1"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**(2)** In your view then you determine if the request is an AJAX request from htmx by checking the headers, in which case you want to only return the result. There are easier or elegant ways to do this (eg. check [`django-htmx`](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-htmx), but just to keep it simple:

```py
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def post_list(request):
    result = 0
    if request.method == "POST":
        num1 = request.POST.get('num_1')
        num2 = request.POST.get('num_2')
        result = int(num1) + int(num2)

    if request.headers.get('Hx-Request') == 'true':
        # return only the result to be replaced
        return HttpResponse(str(result))
    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'result': result})
```

Comment: thank you for your help. However, it reports "Not Found: /favicon.ico" and "Not Found: /post_list". where is wrong?

Comment: Apologies- oversight in my answer. For `hx-post="/post_list"`, you should replace that with the URL to your view as defined in your `urls.py`. If that is called `post_list` (like your view function) than something like `hx-post="{% url 'blog:post_list' %}"` should do the trick.

The `favicon.ico` error is not related to this question and would have showed up anyway, which just means you don't have a bookmark icon set up for your site.

Comment: with this change then it reports another error: "Exception Value: 
'blog' is not a registered namespace"

Comment: this is how my url.py is set: from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list')
]  the basic setting is following this tutorial: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_urls/

Comment: Excellent - in that case it's just `hx-post="{% url 'post_list' %}"` :)

Comment: After I make change for mysite/urls regarding namespace -> urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('', include(('blog.urls','blog'),namespace='blog'))
]  it works!!   Now I am switching to my project about online pricing. I have two result fields need to be displayed rather than one. do I input two hx-targets? like: <form method="POST" hx-post="{% url 'OnlinePricing:OnlinePricing' %}" hx-target="#result_1"> hx-target="#result_2"> ?

Comment: Glad that worked! On your follow-up question: No, the approach would be to produce an entire snippet of HTML that you want to be replaced that contains both of those results. You can also use a Django template with `render()` for that - and just have it contain the snippet. Probably worth watching one or a few of these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=htmx+django)!

Comment: is there a solution for updating multiple result fields? in my case, it's   <div id="charge">
            <label>charge:</label>
            {{ charge }}
        </div>  and id="distance">
            <label>distance:</label>
            {{ distance }}
        </div>  Furthermore, what is correct way to fine tune the view.py request.header that will take in two results? it's almost there, could u please help me on the last bit.

Comment: it seems working, simply by adding two hx-target : <form method="POST" hx-post="{% url 'OnlinePricing:OnlinePricing' %}" hx-target="#charge"> hx-target="#distance">  and for view.py:   if request.headers.get('Hx-Request') == 'true':
   # return only the result to be replaced
   return HttpResponse(str(charge),str(dist))
  else:
   # return render(request, 'OnlinePricing/OnlinePricing.html', {'charge': charge})
   return render(request, 'OnlinePricing/OnlinePricing.html', {'distance': dist, 'charge': charge})

Comment: another thing, when clicking "submit" the user input data will be gone away and only the results will be displayed. how to setup to maintain the user input data so afterwards the user can see both the results and his input at the same time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240666/discussion-between-ad-timmering-and-jack).